# Parent function not sending correct variables to multiprocess child

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a code that is using multi processes to go through a list. Each multiprocess needs to be assigned a number one higher than the previous. I have recreated this issue with the code below where I am attempting to add 1 to the variable x after each multiprocess is created, however, 1 is only getting added to the parent function.

Code:

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Queue
x=0   
def function(variables,q):
    global x
    a='apple'
    reponse_tools=a,x
    list(map(q.put, response_tools))
    return None
if __name__=='__main__':
    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    for i in range(3):
        tools = None
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=function,args=(tools,q))
        p.start()
        print(q.get())#------->>>>>this will print 0 each time
        x+=1
#print(x) ----->>>this will print 3
```

Comment: And? Where did you pass the `x` to the created process?

Comment: `tools` is a tuple of `(0, 'hey')` as you create it. It contains no back reference to `x` or `a`; only the values they previously contained. therefore when you change `x`, `tools` will not change.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for the response! I understand my mistake, however, even if I global x instead of putting it in the function through Queue, then receiving the x variable through Queue as before, the console still prints 0.

Comment: @BahaLooki global won't work here either. you need to pass x itself as an argument. When using the "spawn" start method (default) basically new child processes are a completely different process which then "imports" the main file to be able to access things you've defined. When a file is imported rather than run as the "__main__" file, the `if` clause won't run (which is important so you don't get an infinite loop). `global x` only refers to the copy of `x` in that process, and what you do in the parent process can't modify it.

Comment: Basically `global` can't span across processes.

Comment: @Aaron I am aware that variables are not global across child processes. All I'm attempting to do is x+=1 after I create each multiprocess through the parent, like this: Process 1: x=0, Process 2: x=1, Process 3: x=2. However, in everything I've attempted the processes still respond with x=0.

Comment: `x` in the child process is not created based on the value of `x` in the parent. It only is created by `x=0` when `__main__` is imported. It's like opening a brand new interpreter

Comment: @Aaron Thank You for your help! I will do more research on how to do this and look into the possibility of using a Pool process.

Comment: Imagine it like you write a script, and run it from a command line. then open another command line and instead of opening that script, it instead `import`'s it. the first instance then writes some instructions (what function to call, and what arguments to call with) to a file, and the second instance opens that file and reads it. According to the child process, it defined `x=0` and defined `function` at the import, but never ran any code in the `if` statement. then it read a file telling it to call `function(None, q)`. It was never told what x should be other than 0

Comment: The values `None` and `q` are encoded into text and written to that file btw. (massive simplification, but that basically sums up multiprocessing (using the "spawn" method))

Comment: the simple solution really is just to pass x as an argument `def function(variables, x, q):` `Process(target=function,args=(tools, x, q))`

Answer (score 1):

If you use a `multiprocessing.Pool` instance, the code would look something like the following:

```py
import multiprocessing
from functools import partial


def function(variables, x):
    # variables not used, but it could be
    a = 'apple'
    reponse_tools = a, x
    return reponse_tools

if __name__=='__main__':
    # constant tools:
    tools = None
    worker = partial(function, tools) # first argument to function will be tools
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        results = pool.map(worker, range(3))
    print(results)
```

Prints:

```
[('apple', 0), ('apple', 1), ('apple', 2)]
```